# I can't find xsd.exe in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, xsd.exe

In Visual Studio 2005 the XSD compiler was in the SDK/v2.0 directory. In Visual Studio there is only a SDK/v3.5 directory has gone and so too has the xsd.exe compiler. Where has it gone?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746673/xml-schema-designer-for-visual-studio-2008

Comment: they are refering to the XSD designer, not xsd.exe compiler. Maybe it ships in the same bundle.

Answer (score 28):

Not being completely happy with the above answers I have found that the SDK containing amongst other things the XSD.exe compiler is distributed now as part of the Windows SDK. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/bb980924.aspx?wt.svl=more_downloads

It is distributed as part of the Visual Studio 2008 package but they have moved it from the Visual Studio directory tree to:

on 32bit Windows "Program Files/Microsoft SDKs",
and on 64bit Windows "Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs"

Comment: Did you look where the other answers said to look, and then didn't find it?

Comment: It's not just where to find it, it is also how and why it is where it is. We're building on many developer's machines and also a continuous build server. I want to be able to get veery machine building against a consitent version and location.

Comment: we'll it is the answer I am most happy with ;-) !

Comment: I have VS 2010 installed on Windows 7 64-bit and XSD.EXE is located  here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\xsd.exe`

Comment: What is the version of xsd.exe on your system, after installing the package?

Comment: on my 2008 system it is:
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 9):

I have xsd.exe here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\xsd.exe
```

I have VS2005 and VS2008 installed (and had VS2003 before installed).

Answer (score 7):

I have xsd.exe here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe  So I think you have yours at the Windows Platform SDK corresponding path on your machine. Make sure you have installed PlatformSDK sometimes it can be in VisualStudio directory

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

Or on a 64 bit machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools

Or on a 64 bit machine:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64