# How do I build an .xsd file from xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

Is there a way to generate an xsd from an xml file? Are there any class files that do this? I don't mind if the solution is c# or java.

I would like to do this in code, but if there are any good free tools that would be ok too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) can do what you want:

> If you specify an XML file (.xml extension), Xsd.exe infers a schema from the data in the file and produces an XSD schema. The output file has the same name as the XML file, but with the .xsd extension.

Comment: See to find xsd.exe on your machine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073228/i-cant-find-xsd-exe-in-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 2):

Try xsd command better explained at [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)