# How to create a XSD file from a XML file using VB.net code

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd

How can I generate a xsd file from a XML file using vb.net code?

Comment: You can generate an XSD file from an XML file programmatically, and get an XSD that the XML conforms to, but it's not likely to be very useful. For example, it may well constrain all postcodes to have the pattern AA99 9AA, just because all the postcodes in your sample XML conform to that pattern. In practice to get a useful schema, you need human intervention.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835918/832052) and converted it to vb.net

```vb
Using reader = XmlReader.Create("filename.xml")
    Dim schemaInference = New XmlSchemaInference()
    Dim schemaSet = schemaInference.InferSchema(reader)
    For Each s As XmlSchema In schemaSet.Schemas()
        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create("schema.xsd")
            s.Write(writer)
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

Sometimes it helps to learn about this thing called a [search engine](https://www.google.com/). You may have heard of a [search engine](https://www.google.com/). If so, you can try to search one too!

Try this

> generate xsd from xml vb.net site stackoverflow.com

and if that doesn't work, you can always look for c# answers because they are more abundant

> generate xsd from xml c# site stackoverflow.com

The answer I found was in the first result of the [search engine](https://www.google.com/).